# How to append an object to array in javascript?

Tags: javascript, object

Why is the array getting just the last object?

```
this.checkpoints = new Array();

this.checkpoint = new Object();
    this.checkpoint['lat'];
    this.checkpoint['lng'];

this.checkpoint['lat'] = 1;
this.checkpoint['lng'] = 1;
this.checkpoints.push(this.checkpoint);

this.checkpoint['lat'] = 2;
this.checkpoint['lng'] = 2;
this.checkpoints.push(this.checkpoint);

this.checkpoint['lat'] = 3;
this.checkpoint['lng'] = 3;
this.checkpoints.push(this.checkpoint);

console.log(this.checkpoints);
```

The result is wrong:

```
[Object { lat=3,  lng=3}, Object { lat=3,  lng=3}, Object { lat=3,  lng=3}]
```

But if I try without objects, it's OK:

```
this.checkpoints = new Array();

this.checkpoints.push(1);

this.checkpoints.push(2);

this.checkpoints.push(3);

console.log(this.checkpoints);
```

The result is:

```
[1, 2, 3]
```

Please, what am I missing? Thanks in advance!

Comment: It's because the pushing is reference based. It pushes **`this.checkpoint`**'s address (reference), not it's value.

Comment: I wonder what this :`this.checkpoint['lat'];
    this.checkpoint['lng'];` do

Comment: @RoyiNamir It means you are assigning properties to the object with those names.

Comment: @RaeenHashemi it was not a question but pointing to a _non code_ : http://i.imgur.com/bcVR8o6.png ( line 3 & 4 at OP's code)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because you are just changing the property values of the same object. You need to create 3 different objects.

You can simplify it using [Object Initializer](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer)

```
this.checkpoints = new Array();

this.checkpoints.push({
    lat: 1,
    lng: 1
});
this.checkpoints.push({
    lat: 2,
    lng: 2
});
this.checkpoints.push({
    lat: 3,
    lng: 3
});

console.log(this.checkpoints);
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
this.checkpoint = new Object();
    this.checkpoint['lat'];
    this.checkpoint['lng'];

this.checkpoint['lat'] = 1;
this.checkpoint['lng'] = 1;
this.checkpoints.push(this.checkpoint);

this.checkpoint['lat'] = 2;
this.checkpoint['lng'] = 2;
this.checkpoints.push(this.checkpoint);

this.checkpoint['lat'] = 3;
this.checkpoint['lng'] = 3;
this.checkpoints.push(this.checkpoint);
```

it only changes the checkpoint['lat'] , checkpoint['lng'] property of the checkpoints object so when you execute the

" console.log(this.checkpoints);" statement

it will display only the last changed property value and that is 3 for both ['lat'] and ['lng'] former values are overridden by last one.